# How to I scroll back in multitail when using command line filters

Tags: logging, syslog

I'm currently filtering out unwanted lines when using `multitail`

```
$ multitail -ev "foo|bar" -kr 0 55 -f /var/log/syslog
```

The problem is, when I want to scroll back through the output, the only way I know of how to do this is using the `b` command.  The problem is, `b` brings up a buffer window that has all of the original (unfiltered) lines in it.  How do I scroll through the output without seeing the lines that I don't care about?

Answer (score 1):

It seems not possible to scroll back without engaging the `b` key/command.

There is a feature request about this filed back in 2014. Maybe you can ask for it too and the developer will hopefully make it:
https://github.com/flok99/multitail/issues/1